# How can I let grep scan only the first 12 characters in filename?

Tags: perl, grep

I am trying to filter files by their filename.

You are asked to input two dates, then my code goes through all files and writes all files fitting to the search parameters into an array.

But if I input an inaccurate range like 2014 .. 2016, it happens that files that are not relevant to my search (as I want to grep only the first 8 characters as those represent a datestamp) like the first two files in `@files` are also filtered because they contain 2014, 2015 or 2016 elsewhere in their name.

```
@files = 20120830_600020143_1_Log.csv (wrong because year 2012)
         20130830_600020161_1_Log.csv (wrong because year 2013)
         20150830_600020162_1_Log.csv
         20160830_600020121_1_Log.csv
```

How can I grep only the the first 12 characters of a filename?

I thought of a mix with `substr` but couldn't get it to work.

Here's the code I need to change. In this case `$daterange` is `"2016"`

```
foreach $folder ( @folder ) {

    $curdir = "$scriptdir\\$folder";

    opendir my $dir_b, "$curdir" or die "Can't open directory: $!";
    my @files = grep { /$daterange/ } readdir $dir_b;
    closedir $dir_b;

    foreach $files ( @files ) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: "/$daterange/" to "^$daterange/" ?

Comment: ^regex = amazing things.  Great resource in helping you http://regexr.com/

Comment: yeah, ^ only looks for a 2016 at the beginning of the filename right? somehow this lets me think about possible errors this could cause, cant find any though as long as namesyntax is the same. thank you

Comment: I'm unclear why 2014 .. 2016 is "an inaccurate range"?

Comment: because the user wont (or atleast shouldnt) scan for such a huge amount of data. it is intented to scan for days or weeks, like 20160801 .. 20160901 and not for years, that was what I meant when I wrote "inaccurate range", maybe its the wrong word to describe what I meant :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want to search only the first eight characters of each file name. That would look like this

```
my @files = grep { substr($_, 0, 8) =~ $daterange } readdir $dir_b;
```

I would prefer to use `readdir` in a `while` loop, like this

```
foreach $folder ( @folder ) {

    my $curdir = "$scriptdir\\$folder";

    opendir my $dh, $curdir or die qq{Unable to open directory "$curdir": $!};

    while ( my $node = readdir $dh ) {

        next if $node eq '.' or $node eq '..';
        next unless substr($node, 0, 8) =~ $daterange;

        my $fn = "$curdir\\$node";
        next unless -f $fn;

        # Do stuff with $fn
    }
}
```